# How to make a step-by-step choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a task. It is necessary to give the user a choice in the first step between 3 (input radio). After he chose one of the items he needed, a second column appears with the new column (input radio). And also after the choice in the second step appears the third step with the final choice (input radio).

It is important that the second step and the third for each selected item are new.

Help solve this problem.

I found a similar task, but it's a little unsuitable for my purposes.
[Updating button content based on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778915/updating-button-content-based-on-selection)
[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7w78.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selects = $('.drop-down');
  selects.not(':eq(0)').prop('disabled', true); 
  selects.on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this),
        currentIndex = selects.index(select),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (currentIndex != selects.length - 1) {
      selects.slice(nextIndex)
             .val('')
             .prop('disabled', true);

      selects.eq(nextIndex).prop('disabled', select.val() === '');
    }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="v1" class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Выберите Вид рекламы--</option>
  <option value="1">Объявление [Товар / Услуга]</option>
  <option value="2">Визитная карточка</option>
  <option value="3">Статический баннер</option>
</select><br>
<select name="v2" class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Выберите раздел--</option>
  <option value="1">Товары</option>
  <option value="2">Услуги</option>
  <option value="3">Компании</option>
  <option value="4">Биржа</option>
  <option value="5">Публикации</option>
</select><br>
<select name="v3" class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Конечная категория--</option>
  <option value="1">Весь раздел</option>
  <option value="2">Главная страница</option>
  <option value="3">Категория товара</option>
  <option value="4">Отдельный товар</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us something.

Comment: How do I insert my code here?

Comment: Edit your question and press `Ctrl+M`

Comment: First of all _get rid of all the names in the options_! Since you’re using `name` in the `select` element, the rest will just interfere. Secondly, if you’re using the `name` attribute, you really should put your elements inside a form, preferably with an `id` attribute, so we can find it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hope this is what you want:

will create dependencies between each select and the next one only with CSS.
This might not be a perfect solution but for some situations it might definitely be suffice.

Each `select` must have a `required` attribute for this to work and also there should be no HTML elements between them.

You can extend this approach to pretty much anything you want, including those radio buttons you've mentioned. just add them to the HTML and change the CSS a bit. it was unclear what exactly you wanted, but this gives you 90% of the way to achieve it probably.

```css
select { margin:1em; display:block; }

/* block all but the first "select" elements from being used (like "disabled" */
select:not(:first-child){ opacity:.3; pointer-events:none; }

/* show the next "select" if any select has a value */
select:valid + select{ opacity:1; pointer-events:auto; }
select:invalid{  }
```

```html
<select name="v1" required>
  <option value="">--Выберите Вид рекламы--</option>
  <option value="1">Объявление [Товар / Услуга]</option>
  <option value="2">Визитная карточка</option>
  <option value="3">Статический баннер</option>
</select>
<select name="v2" required>
  <option value="">--Выберите раздел--</option>
  <option value="1">Товары</option>
  <option value="2">Услуги</option>
  <option value="3">Компании</option>
  <option value="4">Биржа</option>
  <option value="5">Публикации</option>
</select>
<select name="v3" required>
  <option value="">--Конечная категория--</option>
  <option value="1">Весь раздел</option>
  <option value="2">Главная страница</option>
  <option value="3">Категория товара</option>
  <option value="4">Отдельный товар</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**jsFiddle** example: https://jsfiddle.net/7c297a3w/

**Javascript**

```
$('input[type="radio"][name^="group-"]').change(function() {
  var container = $(this).parent().parent();
  var nextSiblings = container.nextAll();
  nextSiblings.removeClass('valid');
  nextSiblings.find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
  container.addClass('valid');
});
```

**CSS**

```
[id^="step-"] {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
}

[id^="step-"]:not(:first-child) label {
  opacity: .3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[id^="step-"].valid+[id^="step-"] label {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step-1">
  Step 1
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-1" value="1" required>1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-1" value="2">2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-1" value="3">3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-1" value="4">4</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-1" value="5">5</label>
</div>
<div id="step-2">
  Step 2
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-2" value="a" required>a</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-2" value="b">b</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-2" value="c">c</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-2" value="d">d</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-2" value="e">e</label>
</div>
<div id="step-3">
  Step 3
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-3" value="i" required>i</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-3" value="ii">ii</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-3" value="iii">iii</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-3" value="iv">iv</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group-3" value="v">v</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Very similar to the truth, but how to make sure that each element has its own sub-points?

Comment: You may follow the above html structure, I have already kept it as simple as I can. If you need to change the structure, just amend the selector expression in css and javascript.